# Java selenium ChromeDriver метод setExperimentalOption не работает

Tags: java, selenium, chromedriver

Java selenium ChromeDriver метод setExperimentalOption не работает

Вознаграждение 10$, тому кто первый и точно подскажет в чем проблема

Есть простой код, посмотреть/скачать можно на Git https://github.com/a040985/chromeDriverError
Когда его запускаю в idea всё работает норм.
Но когда запускаю скомпилированный .jar файл через .bat файл, выдает ошибку "NoSuchMethodError:"

Ошибка указывает на метод «options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);», но почему программа не видит этот метод непонятно.
Если убрать этот метод, то всё работает норм, но убрать я его не могу т.к. мне нужно указать путь для сохранения файла.

```
package by.bestproger.project.downloadprice.runner;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RunApp {
    final public static String pathDefault = "D:\\java\\myProject\\downloadprice\\";
    final public static String downloadPathDefault = pathDefault + "externalFiles\\downloadFiles\\";
    final public static String pathGoogleDriver = pathDefault + "externalFiles\\exe\\chromedriver.exe";

    public static ChromeDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        chromeDriver();
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void chromeDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathGoogleDriver);
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadPathDefault);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        //если этот метод закомментить, то всё работает норм,
        // но этот метод нужен для установки пити загрузки файла
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.get("https://www.tut.by/");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНИЕ

1. Меняем pom.xml файл (содержимое ниже)
2. Через консоль "CMD" переходим в папку где лежит файл pom.xml
3. Выполняем команду "mvn package"
4. Эта команда формирует файл в директории проекта "target" с именем "downloadprice-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
5. Просто двойным кликом запускаем файл.

> xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
> [http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd%22%3E)
> 4.0.0
>
> ```
> <groupId>by.bestproger.project</groupId>
> <artifactId>downloadprice</artifactId>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>             <configuration>
>                 <source>8</source>
>                 <target>8</target>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <version>3.2.0</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <id>make-executable-jar-with-dependencies</id>
>                     <phase>package</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>single</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <archive>
>                             <manifest>
>                                 <mainClass>by.bestproger.project.downloadprice.runner.RunApp</mainClass>
>                             </manifest>
>                         </archive>
>                         <descriptorRefs>
>                             <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
>                         </descriptorRefs>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
>
> <dependencies>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
>         <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
>         <version>3.141.59</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
>         <version>1.3.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
>         <version>2.6.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
>         <version>2.6.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
>         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
>         <version>1.3.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.github.junrar</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junrar</artifactId>
>         <version>4.0.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>
> </dependencies>
> ```